# Is it possible to define my own String class?

Tags: java

Is it possible to define my own String class which has the exact same name as java.lang.String? My assumption is that after I have defined it, I can use it directly or load it with a class loader.

Sorry, the code I wrote has a mistake. The String class of the parameter String[] args of the method main() was incorrectly referenced to my own defined String. That is why it occured a compile error.
My working result is that we can define a class named String in my own namespace or java.lang. But since  JVM has loaded the default java.lang.String, we can't load our own String and use it.

Comment: did you even try it ?

Comment: Everything is possible if you believe.

Comment: You want your own String class in the java.lang namespace or in your own package?

Comment: You can make a class called `String`, but it would be very foolish to do so.  You can't really make a class called `java.lang.String` (you can write it, but you can't get a class loader to load it), but if you could, it would be even more foolish.

Comment: This question isn't really downvote-worthy. It's not a *practical* question, but it's clearly defined and can be answered objectively.

Comment: When `public static void main(String[])` is called, `String` (argument type) is already loaded, so any magic you plan with classloaders are deemed to fail.

Comment: You may put your class into rt.jar and substitute String.class. But this is a very bad idea.

Comment: @chrylis Indeed, but it doesn't demonstrate any research or minimal efforts.

Comment: This question isn't really upvote-worthy.  It shows no research effort.  The OP could simply have TRIED THIS OUT, to find out whether it's possible.  Or as the button on the triangle that I clicked says ... "This question does not show any research effort; it is ... not useful (click again to undo)".  The question precisely fits the very definition of a question that should be downvoted.   @chrylis

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want to do this?

Comment: +1, in my opinion a well-formed question. Do remember that questions are the life blood of this site. Let's not get too nasty.

Comment: Year, of cource I have tried it and the String class is defined in my own namespace, but it can't be compiled correctly. The log said can't find main() method after I defined String even I was not using it.

Comment: @yitzih coz I am reading some articles about java reflection today and a friend told me that he was asked this question in an interview. So I want to find out the answer. However I still can't figure out the correct explanation to it after writing some demos.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can *define* that class, but you won't be able to *use* it. The class `java.lang.String` will be loaded out of the JRE at bootstrap, and you can't reload a class in the bootstrap classloader. If you try to use your own classloader, the JVM will notice that `java.lang.String` is already loaded and just use that one.

From [the JLS section on class loading](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2):

> - Given the same name, a good class loader should always return the same class object. *(This means that the `java.lang.String` class that gets pulled in a bootstrap will be the authoritative class.)*
> - If a class loader L1 *(the bootstrap loader)* delegates loading of a class C to another loader L2 *(your own loader)*, then for any type T *(`java.lang.String`)* that occurs as the direct superclass or a direct superinterface of C, **or as the type of a field in C, or as the type of a formal parameter of a method or constructor in C, or as a return type of a method in C,** L1 and L2 should return the same `Class` object. *(Your own `java.lang.String` would be conflicting with all of the parameters and fields in anything else loaded by the bootstrap loader and would cause virtually anything past the loading of your rogue class to come crashing down with link or cast errors.)*

What exactly are you trying to do, anyhow? `java.lang.String` has very strictly defined semantics, and changing its behavior at all would break an enormous amount of code.

Comment: You can make your own classloader which returns your class when asked to load `java.lang.String`. Or are system classes treated specially?

Comment: @immibis It's not so much *system* classes as classes that are loaded in a higher-up classloader you can't control. Very similar situation in application containers where the container supplies API classes such as the Servlet API.